# MYSQL UPGRADE TEMP TABLE SIZE

Tags: mysql, upgrade

After upgrading mysql from 5.6 to 5.7 mysql_upgrade is trying to run ALTER TABLE FORCE on big table.

Will such operation be successful if there is no space for temporary table?
If no, how to omit this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> Will such operation be successful if there is no space for temporary table?

No.

> If no, how to omit this problem ?

Put your MySQL datadir on a disk volume with more free space.

You should always keep at least as much free disk space as the size of your largest db table, otherwise you can't do an ALTER TABLE or OPTIMIZE TABLE that requires a table-copy.